# Refreshing data in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, refresh

Can you refresh data in a Power BI dashboard if you've moved the underlying data source to a different folder? My colleague built a dashboard using data on his desktop. I have to refresh the dashboard, but the updated data now sits on my desktop. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Thanks, @Peter. I was able to change the data source by going to "File -> Options and settings -> Data source settings" in Power BI.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to always import source file from SharePoint using the SharePoint folder connector.

As a quickfix you could also change the path to a local source file by going to the table/query in the PowerQuery Editor. The first ETL step is "Source" and in the formula bar you can see something like

```
Source = Csv.Document(
   File.Contents("C:\Users\login\Downloads\data.csv")
)
```

This is the place where you can simply change the path to the new location.

Comment: But how do I tell Power BI the new location of the data? When I try to refresh the data, Power BI tells me "Could not find part of the path 'C:\xxx\xxx\xxx\DB.xlsx'" (the path where the original data was). Power BI doesn't give me any option to change the pathname to SharePoint.